# Jquery UI modal with right margin on text input

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to get rid of those margins but i am struggling to find how and where to change it.I tried to override jquery and bootstrap css but with no luck (was playing with 0 margin) . The class which apply that margin is "text" class-if I delete it there are no margins but also rest of the formatting is gone which is not good for me . Any hints are welcome

[image]

This is my definition:

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">    

                Street</label>
            <input type="text" name="CompanyStreet" id="CompanyStreet" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"/>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">


            <input type="text" name="PostCode" id="PostCode" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"/>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <label for="CompanyCity">

            <input type="text" name="CompanyCity" id="CompanyCity" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"/>  
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <label for="CompanyCountry">

            <input type="text" name="CompanyCountry" id="CompanyCountry" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"/> 
            </div> 
        </div>
```

Comment: you want that no margin right

Comment: First of all, post the CSS aswell. Secondly, you can use the inspect tool and see exactly where the `margins/padding` come from.

Comment: you using bootstrap4 or bootstrap3?

Comment: sorry guys i figured this out- it was bootstrap column margins and not the elements. i used row no-gutter class .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For v4, all you need to do is apply [`no-gutters`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#how-it-works) class to your `.row` element. And a few minor styling details such as `<input>` border-radius or bringing the focused input to front:

```css
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .my-row input {
    border-radius: 0;
    width: calc(100% + 1px);
  }
  .my-row input:focus {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .my-row .form-group:first-child input {
    border-radius: .25rem 0 0 .25rem;
  }
  .my-row .form-group:last-child input {
    border-radius: 0 .25rem .25rem 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .my-row label {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters my-row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
            <label for="CompanyStreet">Street</label>
            <input type="text" name="CompanyStreet" id="CompanyStreet"
            value="" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
            <label for="PostCode">Post Code</label>
            <input type="text" name="PostCode" id="PostCode" value=""
            class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
            <label for="CompanyCity">Company City</label>
            <input type="text" name="CompanyCity" id="CompanyCity"
            value="" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
            <label for="CompanyCountry">Company Country</label>
            <input type="text" name="CompanyCountry" id="CompanyCountry"
            value="" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Same thing, for v3:

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .my-row > .form-group {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .my-row > .form-group label {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .my-row > .form-group input {
    border-radius: 0;
    width: calc(100% + 1px);
  }
  .my-row > .form-group input:focus {
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
  }
  .my-row > .form-group:first-child {
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
  .my-row > .form-group:first-child input {
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  }
  .my-row > .form-group:last-child {
    padding-right: 15px;
  }
  .my-row > .form-group:last-child input {
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .form-group label {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row my-row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
      <label for="CompanyStreet">Street</label>
      <input type="text" name="CompanyStreet" id="CompanyStreet" value="" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
      <label for="PostCode">Post Code</label>
      <input type="text" name="PostCode" id="PostCode" value="" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
      <label for="CompanyCity">Company City</label>
      <input type="text" name="CompanyCity" id="CompanyCity" value="" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
      <label for="CompanyCountry">Company Country</label>
      <input type="text" name="CompanyCountry" id="CompanyCountry" value="" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Side note: your markup is invalid, it has quite a few unclosed tags. You might want to run it through a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: Andrei can You give me some more details ? which unclosed tags ?

Comment: @rafa: all your `<label>`s are either not started or not finished, except second one, which is missing entirely. Paste your "definition" in the validator I linked and it will tell you. BTW, why are you calling it a "definition"? It's **markup**.

Answer (score 0):

Niether Bootstrap 3 or 4 has a .text class, so either this is a class you created yourself, or it isn't actually doing anything.

It seems to me that the space your seeing is probably the "gutters" of each column. Bootstrap columns have default padding of 15px on left and right, so that creates 30px of space between two columns.

With that being said you have three options:

**1. Override the padding for the columns and see if this fixes your issue.**

```
    [class^="col"] {
        padding: 0
    }
```

You can be more specific to select only these columns if this solution works, to only apply it to these fields.

**2. Put these fields into a single column and space them out yourself**

Since these fields don't necessarily need to be in their own columns, you can put try a col-*-12 and space them yourself.  This would eliminate the default padding between columns.

**3. Apply the no-gutter class to the row and see if it solves your issue.**

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys i figured this out- it was bootstrap column margins and not the elements. i used row no-gutter class